# Assign unique ID to ArrayAdapter buttons in java

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom ArrayList which I am using to populate an Activity, this ArrayList takes a ListView of a prepopulated Array of Strings, each unique. In this instance I am taking a list of Band names (which can change).

The ArrayAdapter is populated by this ArrayList and inserted into a layout block which contains an XML button.

> Main

```
ArrayList<String> BandList = Controller.BandInfo();

findtheListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.findtheListView);
newAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listviewrow, BandList);
findtheListView.setAdapter(newAdaptor);
```

> Listview_row

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:padding="20dp"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:onClick="onClickdoAction">
```

The list populates with no problem inserting all my values, the problem I'm having is the button has the same id for each new populated button.

On clicking I have a function which finds the value of the button and goes to a certain page depending on the button.
Clicking on a button, however, just finds the information from the first defined button.

How would I give each button a unique ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are struggling with click on each button use this solution

```
findtheListView.setOnItemClickListener((new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

  @Override 
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<> parent, View view, int position, long id)
  { 
    // your code here based on position. 
    // You can use bandlist for getting data at that position 
  } 

});
```

Regards,
Sha

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea about a button have a unique ID,but maybe u can try  Button.setTag(Object), set unique value for per button. And when click can use  View.getTag() gain the unique value which previous setted